# Best practices for throwing exceptions that are to be displayed to the user

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Unexpected exceptions that should terminate execution of the program are simply thrown. They are caught by `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` and taken care of there - logged if necessary, and a generic "This app is about to crash and you have nothing to do about it" message displayed to the user.

But what about those exceptions that only need to cancel an operation, while showing the user a more useful message? e.g. informing the user that a file can't be accessed because it's being used by another process. This exception might be deeply nested, and I wouldn't want to check for some flag at every method return. I'd rather have something like this: when the user initiates the most "external" method - say, a button click event handler, the code will include a try-catch block catching all `DisplayToUserException`'s , and rethrow any other exceptions. So I'll have to create this custom exception class.

But before I go down that path, I'd like to know if that's the standard thing to do, or perhaps there's a better solution for this. Or perhaps a class already built for this. Hence this question.

Comment: What kind of application? Winforms?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes. Does it matter? (I now added the tag.)

Comment: a better solution may be to use an `enum` that contain status code information that is mapped somehow to friendly messages. that avoids the heavy overhead of throwing/catching exceptions. just return the status from applicable methods and test them at the call site

Comment: @MikeCorcoran But that would mean that if the exception is deeply nested - I'd have to check methods' return values at every level. As I wrote, I'd like to avoid that, unless it _is_ the only way that would avoid problems.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran: one of the most important aspects of the design of exceptions is to avoid failure to check the return status of methods. Such an enum will be ignored when it should not be ignored.

Comment: It matters because of the nature of the beast. I suspected you were talking in the context of an interactive, desktop-like UI, in which case my answer applies. If it had been a WCF service, for instance, my advice would have been a bit different (handle exceptions in the top-level of each service operation and translate them into appropriate faults).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to put a try/catch block around your UI events:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        // Do something interesting, like calling methods that throw (nested) exceptions
        // Maybe these methods do file I/O
    }
    // Though it's better to catch a more-specific exception or set of exceptions
    catch (IOException ex){ 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

This limits the effects of the exception to the UI operation (the button click, in this case).

A truly unhandled exception, one that you can't anticipate or do anything about, will still get handled by the AppDomain exception handler.

Note also that the `Message` property of an exception *is* meant for display to the user. It's ok to catch a "technical" exception, and rethrow as an exception with a user-friendly message. But be sure to include the original exception:

```
try {
    // Do something with the file name in the <c>path</c> variable
}
catch(IOException ex){
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        String.Format("Can't perform that file I/O on {0}, sorry about that", path), ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But perhaps I wasn't clear enough. My question is about how to notify the user from within a deeply nested method. Simply catching IO exceptions will not have enough information. Unless I analyze it - which method did it come from etc. (perhaps that's a good way, though.) I would like to escape from a nested method directly to the inform the user specific things.

Comment: Thanks. Very good. So I actually don't even need a custom type exception. I can just throw a `new Exception("Message for user", ex)` (or better yet, `IOException` or whatever the origianl was) and take care of it in the `catch` block. I haven't thought of that.

Comment: Right. I usually just use `InvalidOperationException` or something generic like that. A custom exception should really only be used if you'll be catching that particular exception or otherwise taking special action due to the type. I'll change my example.